# Client Object Model, cannot find site user?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-clientobject

I am getting `ServerException` when running the program. Here is my code:

```
 ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://myRUL");
 Principal user = context.Web.SiteUsers.GetByLoginName(@"myRealAccoutLoginIn");
 RoleDefinition readDef = context.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByName("Approve");//"Approve" is the permission I want to give to the user

 RoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefCollection = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context);
            roleDefCollection.Add(readDef);
 RoleAssignment newRoleAssignment = context.Web.RoleAssignments.Add(user, roleDefCollection);

 context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Here is [image]the detail exception:

And I can assure you the `SiteUsers` exist from the website, the red circle from the below image is my sharepoint accout:
[image]

Comment: What line does this error appear on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web.SiteUsers doesn`t exist in SharePoint 2010 and is not recomended in SharePoint 2013.

Try using `Web.EnsureUser("<username>")` ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx)) to get the Principal.

Comment: It worked and I accepted your answer. Another question, is it possible to give certain user permission only to certain library and folders?

Comment: It's possible. You can assign exclusive permissions to users and roles in Libraries, Folders and ListItems/Documents.

Comment: ok. How about using `Client Object Model` and write a program to do it?

Comment: Just changing context.Web.RoleAssignments.Add to context.Web.Lists[<listname].RoleAssignments.Add solves your problem with lists. Works the same with folders and items.

Comment: I asked a new question, please have a look and provide answers so that I can accept answer and give you reputation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754692/how-to-grant-user-permission-to-certain-folders-using-client-object-model